# Magento 2 data migration failure

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, magento-2.1.1

How do we get Magento 2.1.1 migration (from 1.8.1.0) to skip the checks below, so that we can move past these errors?

`[2016-09-13 21:48:27][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-09-13 21:48:27][ERROR]: Class catalog/product_attribute_backend_finishdate does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.backend_model for attribute_id=78
[2016-09-13 21:48:27][ERROR]: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_block_proportions does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=138
[2016-09-13 21:48:27][ERROR]: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_categorylabel does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=141
[2016-09-13 21:48:27][ERROR]: Class seosuite/catalog_product_attribute_source_meta_robots does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=142
[2016-09-13 21:48:27][ERROR]: Class seosuite/catalog_product_attribute_backend_meta_canonical does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.backend_model for attribute_id=143
[2016-09-13 21:48:27][ERROR]: Class seosuite/catalog_product_attribute_source_meta_canonical does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=143
[2016-09-13 21:48:27][ERROR]: Class seosuite/system_config_source_crossdomain does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=144
[2016-09-13 21:48:27][ERROR]: Class seosuite/catalog_product_attribute_source_meta_robots does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=146`

Comment: Anyone able to help on this?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `class-map.xml` to remap the classes. You can leave the `<to>` tag empty to simply ignore the class.

For example, add this to `class-map.xml` to ignore the class `catalog/product_attribute_backend_finishdate`:

```
<rename>
    <from>catalog/product_attribute_backend_finishdate</from>
    <to></to>
</rename>
```

See: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/144

Comment: hi @Lachlan i am getting error like below, Class tm_megamenu/system_config_source_cms_block does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=140, how to fix it?

Comment: Similar issue Jafar, did you find a fix?